# How do I enable OMP on a file that passes through nvcc to VS2015?

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

Title pretty much sums it up. I would like to enable openMP for host code in a file that has to pass through nvcc first. If the following is "test.cu"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::cout << "Hi " << omp_get_thread_num()+1 << "/" << omp_get_num_threads() << "!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile on Ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 8 (nvcc 8.0.44) and g++ 5.4.0 (`nvcc -O2 test.cu -o testCu -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -fopenmp && ./testCu`) I get (as expected):

> Hi 2/3!
>   Hi 1/3!
>   Hi 3/3!

However, using VS2015 I get:

> Hi 0/1!

And, yes, I have enabled `/openmp` (it works fine if I change the name to test.cpp and change the compiler to cl).

Comment: Won't you have to pass the the `/openmp` via an  `-Xcompiler` option to nvcc as well?

Comment: Take a look at the CUDA OMP sample code/ project.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Got it. Care to post an answer or should I?

Comment: If you want to post an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999104/how-do-i-enable-omp-on-a-file-that-passes-through-nvcc-to-vs2015?noredirect=1#comment69206954_40999104) and [Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999104/how-do-i-enable-omp-on-a-file-that-passes-through-nvcc-to-vs2015?noredirect=1#comment69207184_40999104), we have to explicitly pass the `/openmp` flag to cl via nvcc. When using the command line, this is simple. When using Visual Studio, all parameters to cl need to be added in the Property Pages. Open the properties of the project or specific `.cu` file. Configuration Properties > CUDA C/C++ > Host. Add command line options (`/openmp`) to the Additional Compiler Options field.

Doing a sanity check and looking at the CUDA C/C++ > Command Line reveals that it does *not* appear, but by checking the output window we see that there are two `-Xcompiler` arguments passed, one with what appears in CUDA C/C++ > Command Line (e.g. `-Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /FS /Zi  /MD "`) and one with the commands added manually (e.g. `-Xcompiler /openmp`).